# Unsupported rows per page

Tags: primefaces

Today I encountered an issue. So basically I am working with jsps. So I created a user in DB and specified there with a maximum of how many no. of rows per page need to be for that user i.e, 100. But that option(100 is not visible rest options are visible) is not visible on the screen. What might be the issue and please let me know the solution?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.